# How to show a snackbar only when progressbar is visible and not when it becomes invisible. Please see details

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-view, android-handler, android-snackbar

I'm developing an android app in which I'm downloading some data from `Firebase` and showing it in my app.

I have set a `ProgressBar` which becomes visible on launch of the activity and becomes invisible when the data is fully loaded.

I have set up a `Handler` that after 5 secs if the progress bar is visible a `Snackbar` would be shown. The problem is that snackbar is getting shown even when the progress bar becomes invisible before 5 secs.

Here's what I have done:

```
Handler slowInternetConnection = new Handler();
            slowInternetConnection.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (progressBarLoadingRequests.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        snackbar = Snackbar
                                .make(coordinatorLayout, "It seems there is some problem with the network. Please wait...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                        snackbar.show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "not showed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, 5000);
```

I would like to know that whether checking on this: `progressBarLoadingRequests.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE` condition is appropriate to find out if progress bar is visible or invisible?

Or what else I can do to achieve what I want.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

That comparison should be valid.  I have tested it on a sample I have with a progress bar and the statement works.

You could test it though by using a `ProgressDialog` which has a built in function `isShowing()`.  It's simpler than using a ProgressBar because you do not need to to include it in your layout, but it will freeze the layout until the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: if the comparison is valid then why snackbar is getting shown even after progress bar has gone invisible?

Comment: Your code works when I use it inside of my app.  The problem must be with something outside of your code here.  I would assume your `progressBarLoadingRequests` is a public variable.  Maybe it's getting reset somewhere and no longer holds reference to the actual progressbar